# You can easily lift and lower the roller shade with the plastic handle to make it "free stop."

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does "[free stop](https://www.amazon.ca/dp/B0B491SV3Y/ref=sspa_mw_detail_0?ie=UTF8&psc=1&sp_csd=d2lkZ2V0TmFtZT1zcF9waG9uZV9kZXRhaWw&th=1)" mean in:

> Cordless **Free Stop**: The room darkening roller shades are designed to be cordless to ensure the safety of children and pets. You can easily lift and lower the roller shade with the plastic handle to make it **free stop** and keep window treatments in any position you want.

Comment: 'Free stop' is a term used about blinds when they can be made to stop part way between fully closed and fully open. Google 'blind "free stop"' for other usage examples.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: I didn't know that. You should probably post it as an Answer. I haven't actually followed your advice to look it up, so I still don't know if it means you can have the blind (roman roller OR venetian slat) half-way down, ***or*** (slatted blind only) with the slats half-way between open and closed. If the former, presumably the same term could be used of, for example, car side windows.

Comment: I would say the descriptions were not written by a native English speaker – further down is "Easy install for 5 minutes".